# How to hide Site Title and Description for Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a website based on WordPress and installed theme named "Delaware"

The issue with it is that it shows Site name and description as H1 and H2 tags across all pages. I want this in the div tag.

So I've managed to change them to div tag by making changes to the theme editor but now they are appearing in the header visually (ideally this should only be in source code and not appear in UI). All I did was replacing "h1" and "h2" with "div".

As can also be seen marked under the red box in the attached image.

Can anyone suggest where issue might be?
Domain Name: aidenfinserv.com

#### Screenshot of website header

[image: Screenshot of website header]

Comment: Maybe you broke css selectors for this items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace in your theme **style.css** file code:

```
site-logo h1, .site-logo h2, .site-logo p {
text-indent: -9999px;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

with

```
.site-logo p, .site-logo div {
text-indent: -9999px;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue You're life saver :)